Tamagui Expo EAS Build Completes but Shows Errors When Running on Android
Current Behavior
When running eas build --profile development --platform android on apps/expo the app throws unmatched routes for the initial auth screens and NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null. This doesn't happen on Expo Go, I already tried reinstalling deps.
I saw this related issue pointing out failures when building: https://github.com/tamagui/tamagui/issues/186
but my dev build was able to complete just fine and only throws errors when actually running the app on the device.

Expected Behavior
The app should run the same way with Expo Go only in a development build.
Tamagui Version
"tamagui": "^1.114.4"

Platform
Android

Reproduction
I use this starter template:
https://github.com/tamagui/starter-free

and run `eas build --profile development --platform android` on `apps/expo`

I'm using Expo SDK 51 and React Native's AsyncStorage:

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

and this works fine when I run the app on Expo Go.

my eas.json:

{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 14.0.3",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true,
        "image": "latest"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      }
    }
  }
}

System Info
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.6",
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@tamagui-extras/core": "^1.12.3",
    "@tamagui-extras/form": "^1.17.3",
    "@tamagui/cli": "^1.114.4",
    "check-dependency-version-consistency": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^9.3.0",
    "husky": "^9.1.6",
    "node-gyp": "^10.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "turbo": "^1.13.4",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2",
    "vitest": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "22",
    "npm": "10.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@biomejs/biome": "^1.9.3"
  }

